# background-size contain not working when rendering VF page as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I'm working on Visualforce pages rendered as PDFs. I've been using `background-size: contain` on divs where I want the image (set as a bg image) to shrink so it does not overflow the page or certain regions I wanna keep fixed. This already works on one of my pages but not on another. I mean, the image does not shrink to be seen completely in the div.

The one that's working:

```
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; width: 50%;">
  <apex:repeat value="{!celdaImg.attachments}" var="imagen">
    <div style="background-image: url('{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, imagen.Id)}');" class="image">
  </div>
  </apex:repeat>
</td>
```

The style class "image":

```
.image {
  background-size:contain; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  width: 100%; height: 400px; 
  background-position: center;
}
```

For the one that didn't work I copied the same style. The only difference is it's not inside a table. Just divs. Since it didn't work I tweaked it as follows, adding `!important` and making sure the image is set before the size:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!evidencia.attachments}" var="adjunto">
  <div class="container"><div style="
    background-image: url('{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, adjunto.Id)}');
      background-size: contain !important;" 
  class="image"></div></div>
</apex:repeat>
```

The difference is only I added a containing div for the one that actually displays the image. The style of that outer div is:

```
.container {
  display: table-cell; /* because the other one worked inside a table cell */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

What can I try to have this image shrink to fit completely in a div smaller than it?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce PDF engine do not support all CSS3 tags. AS `background-size` need CSS3 support, that's why it is not working. here is a work-around for `background-size` property. Hope this will help.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="pdf">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box {
                position:relative;
                width:384px;
                height:256px;
                border:3px double #f00;
                margin:10px auto;
            }
            #box img {
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            #box div {
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                color:#fff;
                line-height:256px;
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.simpson)}" alt=""/>
            <div>this is some content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: how can I keep the aspect ratio with this solution? that is why I used background size contain and it DID work already on a VF rendered as PDF!!